# inputHidden how to fetch value from backbean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el, hidden-field

I have an inputHidden element in a form to which i would like to fetch a property value from the backbean. Here is my JSF code:

```
<h:form id="imageEditor">
    <p:toolbar id="theMenuBar">
            <p:toolbarGroup align="left">
            ...
                <p:commandButton value="Quit" ajax="true"
                    action="#{imageEditorBean.goToMainMenu()}"
                    icon="ui-icon-close" >
                    <p:ajax update="@this" immediate="true"/>
                </p:commandButton>
        </p:toolbarGroup>
    </p:toolbar>
    ...  
    <p:fieldset id="viewer" legend="Viewer">    
        <h:inputHidden id="getJSONData" value="#{imageAnnotations.fetchJSONString()}">
        </h:inputHidden>
    ...
```

My corresponding backbean class is:

```
@ManagedBean(name="imageAnnotations")
public class ImageAnnotations  {

    private String jsonString;

    public String fetchJSONString () {

        jsonString = new String();
        ...//populate property
        return jsonString;
    }

    public String getJsonString() {
        return jsonString;
    }

    public void setJsonString(String jsonString) {
       this.jsonString = jsonString;
    }
```

When the page loads value property of inputHidden field is populated BUT when i press the quit button to switch view the button is not working, and i get the following error:

```
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /views/image-editor.xhtml @110,82 value="#{imageAnnotations.fetchJSONString()}": Illegal Syntax for Set Operation
```

I have also tried to call my backbean class and populate the jsonString property like:

```
<h:inputHidden id="getJSONData" value="#{imageAnnotations.jsonString" action="#{imageAnnotations.fetchJSONString()}">
```

with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: You should be mentioning <h:inputHidden id="getJSONData" value="#{imageAnnotations.fetchJSONString()}"> as  <h:inputHidden id="getJSONData" value="#{imageAnnotations.jsonString}"> then only value get set to the field as well as create getter/setter for the same.

Comment: h:inputHidden cannot have an "action" attribute. It's used to store some value. So if value="#{imageAnnotations.jsonString}", then your backing bean must have an attribute called jsonString with public non-static getters and setters for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inputHidden works in the same way as a inputText, except that it's not displayed in the screen. Therefore, the value property has to point to an attribute in the managed bean, with getter and setter. It can't point to a method. You will have to initialize the value of the property either in the constructor or in the @PostConstruct. If in order to populate this property you use a @ManagedProperty or a @EJB, you'll have to do it in the @PostConstruct since in the constructor they haven't been set yet.

```
<h:inputHidden id="getJSONData" value="#{imageAnnotations.jsonString" >
```

In the ManagedBean

```
@ManagedBean(name="imageAnnotations")
public class ImageAnnotations  {

    private String jsonString;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
           jsonString = ... // populate jsonString
    }

    // getter & setter for jsonString
}
```